# React-planner Threejs doesn't load texture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I have installed [`react-planner`](https://github.com/cvdlab/react-planner) that uses three.js as a package into a react app and managed to get it to render etc. The planner uses a catalog that contains several items that have their own respective textures, I have saved this alongside my src folder in the main app as well according to how their demo is set up.

When loading the app in the react app it doesn't load the textures or any images and leaves the elements without the required textures, instead its a simple gray colour in the case of the wall.

However when I run the package by itself through its own webpack config it does manage to load all the required textures and files.

This is the code for the wall:

```
import {ElementsFactories} from 'react-planner';

const info = {
  title: 'wall',
  tag: ['wall'],
  description: 'Wall with bricks or painted',
  image: require('./wall.png'),
  visibility: {
    catalog: true,
    layerElementsVisible: true
  }
};

const textures = {
  bricks: {
    name: 'Bricks',
    uri: require('./textures/bricks.jpg'),
    lengthRepeatScale: 0.01,
    heightRepeatScale: 0.01,
    normal: {
      uri: require('./textures/bricks-normal.jpg'),
      lengthRepeatScale: 0.01,
      heightRepeatScale: 0.01,
      normalScaleX: 0.8,
      normalScaleY: 0.8
    }
  },
};

export default ElementsFactories.WallFactory('wall', info, textures);
```

This is the part of my wall-factory-3d.js that I presume takes in the texture and is what I presume responsible for applying the texture to the wall object:

```
const applyTexture = (material, texture, length, height) => {
  let loader = new TextureLoader();

  if (texture) {
    material.map = loader.load(texture.uri);
    material.needsUpdate = true;
    material.map.wrapS = RepeatWrapping;
    material.map.wrapT = RepeatWrapping;
    material.map.repeat.set(length * texture.lengthRepeatScale, height * texture.heightRepeatScale);

    if (texture.normal) {
      material.normalMap = loader.load(texture.normal.uri);
      material.normalScale = new Vector2(texture.normal.normalScaleX, texture.normal.normalScaleY);
      material.normalMap.wrapS = RepeatWrapping;
      material.normalMap.wrapT = RepeatWrapping;
      material.normalMap.repeat.set(length * texture.normal.lengthRepeatScale, height * texture.normal.heightRepeatScale);
    }
  }
};
```

The catalog isn't registering the JPG and the PNG files for the textures nor the elements.

This is what I see when I run the app using its own webpack
[image: This is what I see when I run the app through its own webpack]

[image: The element uses its texture here when the app is running using its webpack]

And this is what I see when I use it as a package, it is getting the planner-element.js file but not registering the textures or any images from the catalog folder for some reason?
[image: This is what I see when I run the app in another react app as a package]

[image: And finally when I run it as a package it doesn't use the textures from the catalog]

What should I look for or investigate? The main app is a standard react app, the package is using older webpack and is a class based app that has no maintainers anymore so its not possible for me to get help from them unfortunately.

I am wondering if it is loading the URL wrong for the textures/images?
Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!